# iTextSharp HTML to PDF doesn't render cell height correct after update

Tags: c#, itext, html-rendering

After an upgrade from iTextSharp 5.5.4.0 to 5.5.5.0 the rendering table cels from HTML to PDF isn't correct.
The cells are way to high.

I didn't change anything in the code, the only thing I did was upgrading my DLL.

Is my code incorrect, or is this an error in the new version of iTextSharp.

My input files:

- [input HTML](http://www.estrategy.nl/stackoverflow/input.html.txt)
- [input CSS](http://www.estrategy.nl/stackoverflow/schedule_print.css)

My output:

- [v5.5.4.0 output (CORRECT)](http://www.estrategy.nl/stackoverflow/schedule-v5540.pdf)
- [v5.5.5.0 output (WRONG)](http://www.estrategy.nl/stackoverflow/schedule-v5550.pdf)

Below my code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a pdf based on a
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xHTMLContent"></param>
/// <param name="cssContent"></param>
/// <param name="outputStream"></param>
public static void CreateReportFromXHTML(string xHTMLContent, string cssContent, Rectangle pageSize, Stream outputStream)
{
    using (Document document = new Document(pageSize, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f))
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.Open();
        try
        {
            // CSS
            var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
            cssResolver.AddCss(cssContent, true);

            // HTML
            XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
            fontProvider.Register(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Verdana.ttf"));
            fontProvider.Register(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Verdana-Bold.ttf"));
            CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
            htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            // Pipelines
            PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

            // XML Worker
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
            XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

            byte[] baContent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xHTMLContent);

            using (MemoryStream msContent = new MemoryStream(baContent))
            {
                p.Parse(msContent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like something that should be posted as a support ticket on https://jira.itextsupport.com/ rather than a question for StackOverflow, doesn't it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie This is only for registered (payed) users. The refer to StackOverflow for non paying users

Comment: @tom This is a whole other component, using to convert to PDF. Not iTextSharp

Comment: I posted a ticket to JIRA in your place. As you are not a paying customer, you must be an AGPL user which means you are publishing the complete codebase of your application as AGPL too. I'd be interested to see that code. I'm always interested in nice open source use cases.

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem,  I know and I am currently using it in production without any Flickr !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to actually be with your CSS:

```
td .group
{
    width: 140px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

That literally is read as "any *children* of a `td` tag that has a `class` of `group` should have this rule". You, however, are using that class directly on the `td` tag so you should omit the space between the tag and the class selector. Making that simple change in my tests makes your table appear as you want it.

```
td.group
{
    width: 140px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```